# Make Entity Framework reuse a value

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

Whenever I need to filter multiple values by the same value, as follows:

```
.Where(lead => lead.UpdateDate >= lastupdatedDate 
|| lead.Address.lasUpdateDate >= lastupdatedDate
)
```

it generates something like this:

```
select *
from lead
where UpdateDate >= @p__linq__1
or lasUpdateDate >= @p__linq__2
```

and then passes the value twice.  Is there a way to make the generated sql cleaner and have it only pass lastupdatedDate once and reuse the variable?

Comment: I don't think this is possible or desirable. I suspect that EF is creating separate parameters because it's straightforward. Any logic to consolidate parameters would add overhead to the query generation for all queries containing multiple parameters, even if there is no overlap.

Comment: Solving this is not a good use of your time as a programmer.  [The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/).  ... And that is perhaps the most tragic thing about letting yourself get sucked into micro-optimization theater -- it distracts you from your real goal: writing better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is EF6 query translation defect.

The only (ugly) workaround I know is to emulate `let` clause by using two intermediate projections - first to wrap the variable and the query element in anonymous type and second to unwrap the element after applying the filter using the wrapped variable:

```
.Select(lead => new { lead, lastupdatedDate }) // (1)
.Where(e => e.lead.UpdateDate >= e.lastupdatedDate 
    || e.lead.Address.lasUpdateDate >= e.lastupdatedDate)
.Select(e => e.lead) // (2)
```